# find two controls point from two endpoint Bezier Curve

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

Can I find the control points for a Bezier Curve if I have the two end point?

I have an array of endpoint, so I want to find the control point for my application on Javascript Canvas, is it possible?

Comment: For any two end points there is an infinite set of possible control points. You will need to have some sort of constraint to limit the set of possible solutions. Do you have one more point somewhere on the curve or is there a rule that relate the control points from one curve to the next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to define a curve given only 2 points. Even a circular arc with 2 points gives 2 results (clockwise or counter-clockwise).

If your curve is quadratic you will need at least 3 points.

If your curve is cubic you will need at least 4 points.